# squid redirector from https to http

Tags: http, https, squid

Got a problem with squid. I'm using 3.1 version with my own redirector. 
My problem was when a client for example request https://twitter.com (with https) but somehow got a logic with my redirector that twitter.com is invalid page so i redirected this request to my invalid page. Let say 302:http://mydomain.com?invalid=twitter.com, in this stage process will not continue and browser will say "HTTP gateway failed".

So, my theory is when a request is https redirected to http, squid will not work. Is there any configuration i need to be done so that it will work?

Thank you guys..

Answer (score 0):

RFC 2817 isn't very clear about the behavior of  CONNECT and redirect. I think that most of the browser won't accept a redirect as a reply to the CONNECT method. So, there is no way to do what you want.

Is not an Squid issue, is a protocol/browser issue.

Answer (score 0):

well, i think the best way to redirect is when:
- if the request is https the response should be https
- and if the request if http response should be http

that's the best way i can't think at the moment...

Comment: You can't do that in the proxy. The only way is breaking the security and the browsers will complain.